# Reactjs - Popups not shown when called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do something like this on the `onClick` button event,
the Popup shows just once instead of 10 times.
Would appreciate any suggestions.

```js
function ConfirmBeforeDelete() {
   for(let i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
   if(this.state.recordarray.selected){
    showPopup();//ask user if safe to delete
   }
}

render() {
  ...
  <button onClick={ConfirmBeforeDelete}> Delete Records <button/>
  <ModalComponent ... />   
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you use this for loop? Because this loop you are displaying it ten times

Comment: If you are using ``confirm`` dialog box then this might not work. Try creating a custom popup which gets inserted in DOM for each iteration. That way you can maintain multiple popups at same time. Also can you provide the complete code (may be a JS fiddle with minimum code than runs).

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try with a flag:

```
function ConfirmBeforeDelete(){
    let showed = false
    for( let i = 0; i< 10; i++){

    if( this.state.recordarray.selected && !showed){

    showPopup();//ask user if safe to delete
    showed = true;
} }
```